# Does Allah has any shape?

Tags: allah

Assalamualaikum.

My question is simple. Does Allah has any shape? Please, describe with references.

Jajakallah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### سورة الإخلاص:
>
> ولم يكون له كفوا أحد

Meaning: "There is nothing like Him."

We shall not compare His creation with Him. As far as I know, no text indicates that He has a particular shape. As such we have no knowledge about that.

Comment: "There is nothing like Him" does not refer to "He has no shape", Rather "he has such a shape which is very different from any other things." -- is a valid statement. This is a necessary thing and it belongs to Akeedah. Jajakallah.

Comment: @manetsus I think we are spending time on non-issues with little or no added value. Say God has a shape that we do not know and it's part of Aqeedah. Then what? The fact that God is of a completely different nature from His creation may make the word "shape" but that, a word. A word that certainly has little to do with what we can comprehend with our limited intellectual capabilities. By the way, it would be nice if you could indicate the textual evidence on which your answer is based.

Comment: "و لم يكن" و ليس "لم يكون"

Answer (score 1):

```
                                     In the name of Allah
```

In regard to your question:

> Does Allah has any shape?

The answer of your question is **NO**.  Because Allah is not body or material. Accordingly it is not rational or logical to explain how the shape of Allah is. Even there are many things in the world which are not visible (although exist). For instance we know that there is oxygen in the weather, but we cannot see it. (Although Allah is not comparable with anything. Conclusion: Allah is a fact which has not any specific shape, however we can see his power by watching various things which have made by Him.

**Reference:**

[http://t-pasokhgoo.ir](http://t-pasokhgoo.ir/%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%AF%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%DA%A9%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85/172-%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B4%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3%DB%8C,%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%84-%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B4%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3%DB%8C,%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B4%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3%DB%8C,%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B4%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3%DB%8C/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D9%88-%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%DB%8C-%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%87-%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%AB%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%AA%DB%8C%D9%87/2109-%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%86%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%87-%DA%86%D9%87-%D8%B4%DA%A9%D9%84-%D9%88-%D8%AC%D9%86%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%9F.html)

Comment: If No. How will we see God in Jannat My brother?

Comment: @RehanUllah and others: Provide a proof from Quran.

Comment: http://quran.com/75/22-23 @Tarik

Comment: "*The answer of your question is NO*", well dear, the answer is "*We donno*", and it's definitely not "NO". Please correct. Rest of answer you can build upon that.

Comment: @azam The day after you cannot imagine how things look like, taste or smell. Needless to say that what we may perceive of God may have little or nothing to do with what we perceive in Dunia. Is seing physical or spiritual we have no idea of. See  http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura22-aya46.html. In this verse sight is spiritual not physical. Again, who cares as long as we believe and do good deeds.

Comment: @azam Azam has a good point. the answer in not "No" but is "We dont know". It should be the accepted answer!!